# $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = a,$ but $f(x)$ doesn't have a second derivative at $x = a$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Does anyone have an example of a function $f(x)$ which is differentiable at the point $x = a,$ but doesn't have a second derivative at $x = a$?

Comment: $f(x) = (x-a)^2 1_\mathbb{Q}(x-a)$. Then $f$ is only differentiable at $x=a$, is only continuous at $x=1$ hence does not have a second derivative anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
    0& \text{for } x< 0\\
    x^2              & \text{for } x\geq0
\end{cases}$$

then $f'(0)=0$ but $f''(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: @Botond Thanks a lot for the editing!

Answer (score 0):

The primitive(s) of $x\longmapsto |x|$. Namely, $ x\longmapsto \frac12 x|x|+C$.